# Multiple middlewares for routes in Laravel. Array or multiple arguments?

Tags: laravel

I am building a website that, in order to check some of the content, you need to be authenticated AND verified.

When I enclose the middlewares in an array, it works.

```php
Route::resource('premiumContent', 'PremiumContentController')
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

However, when I follow the original documentation,

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#registering-middleware

grouping the middlewares passing them as multiple parameters, it does not work.

```php
Route::resource('premiumContent', 'PremiumContentController')
    ->middleware('auth', 'verified');
```

Only the 'auth' middlewares applies, thus letting me access the content even if I am not verified. Why? What is the right approach?

Comment: Both approaches are fine - the documentation mismatch might be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `web.php` code.This worked for me.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified']], function() {
   Route::resource('premiumContent','PremiumContentController'); 
});
```

Comment: Whomever voted this down, please explain. Aside from the (optional) `'premiumContent','PremiumContentController'` should be `'premiumContent', PremiumContentController::class`, there is no real issue here and should work as per the OP question

Comment: I down voted this answer because this doesn't answer the question. The original question is "__when I follow the original documentation...... but didn't work. why?__" Instead of answering this question you have provided an alternative solution.

Comment: i did not vote up nor down but this is a workaround that is working. It solves my problem but leaves the doubt on why the original documentation is not correct. Thanks anyway for the alternative soluton :)